# PHP Parse string to array

Tags: php, regex

I have this string

```
"{"(2,\"B - Tuna rungu\")","(8,\"C1 - Tuna grahita ringan\")"}"
```

and I wan't to convert this to PHP array, How do I do that in PHP? Is there any built in class that I can use for this?
the array of this string in PHP should be:

```
[[2,"B - Tuna rungu"], [8,"C1 - Tuna grahita ringan"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no class that you can use. You can try some simple string replaces but this is not really stable:

"{" -> [

"}" -> ]

etc.

But what is if you had "{" as proper value in a text field? The correct way is to create a parser/lexer for the syntax of the given string. But for this you need a complete defined syntax with all special cases.

Some information about this:

http://www.codediesel.com/php/building-a-simple-parser-and-lexer-in-php/

Comment: I see so there is no stringtokenizer like in Java, thanks for the link